# Submit data with WebRequest object in get method

Tags: c#, get, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I have the following code:

```
var Instance = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://mywebsite.com/page.aspx"));
var Data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Data["Foo"] = "Bar";
Data["Baz"] = "Paz";
```

How can I submit GET request with the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `GET` method,  you should put your data into the the url.

```
var Data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Data["Foo"] = "Bar";
Data["Baz"] = "Paz";
UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder("http://mywebsite.com/page.aspx");
uri.Query = String.Join("&",Data.Select(x=>String.Format("{0}={1}", 
                                          x.Key, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(x.Value))));


var Instance = WebRequest.Create(uri.ToString());
```

Your url will be:

```
http://mywebsite.com:80/page.aspx?Foo=Bar&Baz=Paz
```